# Is it possible to send 18 watts via USB-A?

Tags: power-supply, usb

Actually this might be a cable question. I see wall warts out there advertising 18 watts.

3A USB Type-A & USB Type-C Wall Charger

- The spec says "Output Voltage- 1 x USB Type-A 18 W"
- I thought the USB-A spec was limited to 3 amps therefore 15 watts but, my question is about the wire. Can any old USB-A to USB-micro handle 15 to 18 watts? -- USB micro: the small trapezoid shaped plug that came with every chargeable device you bought 10-15 years ago.

I'm wondering about powering small audio amplifiers. Probably rarely reaches maximum power consumption but will be continuous running. 5 volt works as I tried it with old lesser amperage warts.  Clearly the manufacturer believes the USB-A end can handle this, but I saw on another thread where someone stated that there was a 9 watt maximum specification somewhere.  Assumedly on the wire or the micro connecter.

It seems there is nothing standard about USB standards.

Comment: I think, this is just one more of the endless USB abuse scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is perfectly possible. The power adaptor for my phone has a USB-A port and came with a USB-A to USB-C cable. Its markings give its rating as 18W and it can supply the following output voltages if the device plugged into it requests them through the USB-PD protocol:

- 5V @ 3A (15W)
- 9V @ 2A (18W)
- 12V @ 1.5A (18W)

So can it supply 18W? Yes. But can it supply 18W at 5V? No.

> It seems there is nothing standard about USB standards

On the contrary, the standards are well-defined and documented, if somewhat complex and hard work to understand. The issues, among others, are the manufacturers that don't adhere to them and the sellers that don't really know what they're talking about.

Comment: Technically there are industrial-grade USB-A plugs and receptacles rated at 5A, check, say, Digi-Key. So 25W @5A from Type-A port is technically possible if the device is used with OEM-supplied cable/connector.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a screen clip from a [Huawei website](https://consumer.huawei.com/en/accessories/superpower-wall-charger-max-88w/) describing one of their 88W chargers:

[image]

The cable is marked 6A which would be 30W. So the answer to your title question appears to be 'yes'.

It's implied that the USB-A to USB-C cable must include an e-mark chip to enable the higher currents.

As to a USB-A to micro-USB, I believe the highest common rating of the latter is 2A so the answer to the question in the text would be 'no', 10W would be about it, and 7.5W would be safer.

If you need more power, I would be looking at PD over USB-C to USB-C which can give you more than 60W (even >100W) at a more pleasant current and voltage combination, and from tiny GaN technology chargers. It's still a dog's breakfast though (of what works and what doesn't).

On the plus side, there are now easy hardware ways of negotiating for the voltage and current you need without even needing a microcontroller, let alone writing code.